# Inline enumerated lists mod 2

Tags: lists

Consider the **MWE**:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}
\item \foo\ \foo
\item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo\ \foo}\
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}} \foo\ \foo\ \foo\ 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first paragraph shows an inline list produced with `enumitem` package. It is nice!

But I'd like an easy way to obtain the result as shown in the second paragraph.

That is, I'd like the counter mod 2 and also an easy way to format the labels and item contents according to the parity.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own inline `enumerate*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}

\newenvironment{enumerate*}
  {\setcounter{enumi}{0}% Restart the list item counter
   \renewcommand{\item}{% Update \item to ...
     \ifvmode\else\unskip\hspace{.5em}\fi% ... insert space before label
     \refstepcounter{enumi}% ... step the enumi counter
     \ifodd\value{enumi}
       \normalfont\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}\itshape
     \else% \value{enumi} is even
       \normalfont\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\theenumi.}}%
       \setcounter{enumi}{0}% Reset counter
     \fi
     \hspace{.5em}% Space after item label
     \nobreak% Avoid breaks after setting the label + space
   }
  }{}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}
  \item \foo\ \foo
  \item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
  \item \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo\ \foo}\
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}} \foo\ \foo\ \foo\ 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following and adjust to your needs:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\modtwolabel}[1]{\ifodd#1%
                           \textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}}%
                         \else 
                           \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}}%
                         \fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label={\protect\modtwolabel{\value*}}]
\item \foo\ \foo
\item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo\ \foo}\
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}} \foo\ \foo\ \foo\ 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo}

\end{document}
```

> [image: inline enumerate mod two]

With a bit of extra markup this will also influence the item contents. In passing I learned of `enumitem`'s `\AddEnumerateCounter` which promised a cleaner interface to my `\modtwolabel`, but couldn't get it to work.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newif\ifoddlabel
\newcommand*{\modtwolabel}[1]{\ifodd#1%
                           \textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}}%
                           \global\oddlabeltrue
                         \else 
                           \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}}%
                           \global\oddlabelfalse
                         \fi}

\newcommand*{\sigur}{\relax\ifoddlabel\itshape\fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label={\protect\modtwolabel{\value*}}]
\item\sigur \foo\ \foo
\item\sigur \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item\sigur \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo\ \foo}\
\textbf{\textcolor{blue}{2.}} \foo\ \foo\ \foo\ 
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{1.}} \textit{\foo}

\end{document}
```

> [image: inline enumerate with mod two contents two]

Comment: Good. So the label problem was solved. Remains the item contents. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using the command `\sigur`?

Comment: `\sigur` is an extra mark-up after `\item`, it checks a flag which was set from inside the label. `egreg`'s answer avoids that with a bunch of `\aftergroup`'s to strategically insert a `\itshape`. In my proposal, you do the insertion yourself but in a way allowing you later on toc permute items, the oddness of the label is computed automatically.

Comment: I asked since I didn't see it being used anywhere. Defined but not used.

Comment: it is used in the second code sample...

Comment: Ow, sorry, I see, after `\item`. I was only reading the preamble.

Answer (score 5):

It's not really clear why you'd want to do it, but here it is.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\agi{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\itshape}
\newcommand\agu{\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\upshape}

\newrobustcmd{\SP}{}
\newrobustcmd{\modulotwo}[4]{%
  % #1 = color for odd, #2 = color for even, #3 = format, #4 = counter
  \upshape
  \ifodd#4\relax
    \def\SP{1}\textcolor{#1}{#3}\aftergroup\agi
  \else
    \def\SP{2}\textcolor{#2}{#3}\aftergroup\agu
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\modulotwo{red}{blue}{\SP.}{\value*}]
\item \foo\ \foo
\item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\bigskip

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\modulotwo{red}{blue}{(\SP)}{\value*}]
\item \foo\ \foo
\item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item \foo
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the third argument to `\modulotwo` you specify the formatting; the number (1 or 2) is represented by `\SP`.

---

A different implementation without `enumerate` that doesn't really seem what you need.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{twovoices}
 {\setcounter{twovoices}{0}%
  \trivlist\item\relax\hspace{\parindent}\hspace{-\voiceindent}%
  \let\item\twovoicesitem}
 {\endtrivlist}
\newcommand{\twovoicesitem}{%
  \stepcounter{twovoices}%
  \upshape\hspace{\voiceindent}%
  \ifodd\value{twovoices}%
    \textcolor{red}{1.}\itshape
  \else
    \textcolor{blue}{2.}%
  \fi
  \nolinebreak\enspace\ignorespaces
}
\newcounter{twovoices}
\newlength{\voiceindent}
\setlength{\voiceindent}{2em plus .5em minus .5em}

\newcommand{\foo}{Very long text to fill some lines}
\begin{document}

\begin{twovoices}
\item \foo\ \foo
\item \foo\ \foo\ \foo
\item \foo
\end{twovoices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It will be used to split a long paragraph to be read by 2 people. I'll read your code.

Comment: I liked the second solution. It is simpler and easy to control spaces around items. Thanks.